# What's the difference between _keras_shape and _shape for a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, shapes

In tensorflow, I find that a tensor has two variable: `_shape` and `_keras_shape`. The following picture is an example:

[image]

The `K.int_shape()` would return the `_keras_shape`.

What's the difference between `_shape` and `_keras_shape`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is already mentioned in the picture above. See the output type. One is `tuple` while other output is of type `TensorShape`. 
For Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128])
a.shape
# output: TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(128)])

from keras import backend as K
print(K.int_shape(a))
# output: (None, 128)
```

`tf.keras.backend.int_shape` returns the shape of tensor or variable as a `tuple` of int or None entries while `_shape` is of type the `TensorShape`.

Read more about `tf.keras.backend.int_shape` from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/int_shape) and `TensorShape` from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape).

Comment: Sorry, My question is: Why the  _keras_shape=(None,2000,4)? What if I input a data (batch, 2500, 4)? If the shape=(2,?,?), my new data is OK. But if the shape=(None,2000,4), my new data would cause an error. I just want know why they are different?

Answer (score 0):

The keras layer would compute the shape of the tensor, but the tensorflow would not. In this way, the _keras_shape was the shape calculated by the self defined layer.